# Error _code:Forbidden (403). Python Django: When logged in user refreshes page

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

Here is how I defined my user_login view function

```
def login_user(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                albums = Album.objects.filter(user=request.user)
                return render(request, 'violin/index.html', {'scale': scale})
            else:
                return render(request, 'music/login.html', {'error_message': 'Disabled account: Contact admin'})
        else:
            return render(request, 'violin/login.html', {'error_message': 'Invalid credentials'})
    return render(request, 'violin/login.html')
```

> Here is my code error: Forbidden (403)

## How do I solve this problem?

Comment: The error happens when a logged-in user views the page, but not when a not-logged-in user views it?  That seems odd, as GET requests will execute only the final `render`, which seems completely agnostic about logged-in status.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, when user refreshes page, the user is already logged in.
The page would be 'violin/index/html'.
The request.method is GET. In the view, if the request.method is GET, it'd go to else statement. But there is no else statement, so it would return the last line of code (render(request, 'violin/login.html'). So two templates are trying to be rendered in same request. That's forbidden. That's why the status code is 403. Either you could redirect the user to another view after login, or you need to write an else statement.
But redirecting to another view would be much better.

```
def login_user(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None: 
            if user.is_active: 
                login(request, user) 
                return redirect('index_view') 
            else: 
                return render(request, 'music/login.html', {'error_message': 'Disabled account: Contact admin'})
        else: 
            return render(request, 'violin/login.html', {'error_message': 'Invalid credentials'}) 
    return render(request, 'violin/login.html', {})
```

You need to write another view for 'index.html'.

Something like this,

```
def index_view(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        albums = Album.objects.filter(user=request.user)
        return render(request, 'violin/index.html', {'albums':albums})
    else:
        return Http404
```

Comment: I tried that like this: `return render(request, 'music/login.html',  {})` but I still get the same error

Comment: what is the variable scale, which you are passing in the context dictioanary

Comment: Here is how my app is structured: There is a general homepage, then a homepage(index.html) which a user with valid account can access. Now from the index.html page I want the user to be able to access any other view and be able to roll back to index.html or just to refresh index.html without needing to reenter his user credentials.

Comment: Yeah.. then write separate views for login and index. login and index can't be in the view. That's what I m saying

Comment: You should write a login view and render a login template, then after login redirect to the index view, which can only be accessed by a logged in user. So, if login fails, the user cant access index, but be stuck in login page. Each view can only render single template at a time. Two views, two templates. Try the above code.